# MongoYii opening multiple connections - PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I am using Mongoyii extension to connect to mongodb, my connection code is as below

```
'mongodb' => array(
'class' => 'EMongoClient',
'server' => 'mongodb://123.456.7.890:12345',
'db' => 'dabatase'
),
```

I have different sections like section a, section b, section c, section d in my Yii application, preceded with login, to access those sections.

1.Now when I log into my application on login page, one connection is done to mongodb, which I am able to see in mongodb's log.

2. After logging, when I click on any of the sections, sometimes, it creates a new connection per section and sometimes not.

I am unable to find exact reason for the same.

I have several queries:

1. Ideal connection time out of mongoyii?
2. When I logout, I want to close all connections that YII app made, how can it be done?
3. If a connection is already done, YII app should check for the same, and use the same, rather than creating new connection. How this can be done?

Comment: Are you using PHP-fpm or the Apache module?

Comment: Sorry Sammaye, but i don't know about PHP-fpm, will be thanking you, if you can explain me the same, currently am hosting my YII app on Apache server

Comment: I believe that Apache should actually be making a connection per process in its default fork mode, are you sure a connection is not made per request? It could also timeout based for the process actually, since that is how PHP works

Comment: Sammaye, i would humbly again repeat :

1.Now when I log into my application on login page, one connection is done to mongodb, which I am able to see in mongodb's log.

After logging, when I click on any of the sections, sometimes, it creates a new connection per section and sometimes not.

My question is, it sometimes creates new connection on click of every section, and the same thing, am able to see in mongo db's log

Comment: And I am guessing a section is a page, i.e. per section is a request right?

Comment: Yes Sammaye, section is a page

Comment: Then my third comment applies since a page (without additional AJAX etc calls) is a request, that's the proper term for it

Comment: Thank you Sammaye for your reply, but as am using single YII application, I want that, my whole YII application should use same connection rather than creating new connection per page, as there are many pages in my app, so creating new connection on every page request is not a good idea.

so is it possible through mongoyii?

Comment: No, it is not possible full stop, even using php-fpm, that is not how servers work

Comment: Well what I mean is that is not how non-deamon programming languages work. PHP is not a deamon, unlike say, Java.